# Evaluate the line integral over the curve of intersection

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem, quadrics

Evaluate $\int_c \frac{y^2}{2}dx + zdy + xdz$, where $c$ is the curve of intersection of the plane $x+z = 1$ and ellipsoid $x^2+2y^2 + z^2  = 1$.

The keyword "intersection" guided me to set the two equations equal: $x+z = 1 = x^2+2y^2+z^2$ and I think that I am supposed to discover some hint here, but I cannot seem to recognize the geometric shape this equation is giving me(can't match the quadric surface formulas I know), can anyone provide a hint?

Comment: Solve the plane equation for $z$ and substitute that into the other.

Comment: The curve does not look like it is closed from the graph

Comment: I don't know what your graph shows, but the non-planar surface does *not* represent $x^2+2y^2+z^2=1$.

Comment: It's an implicit surface I graphed on Calcplot 3D

Comment: Now I see! Thx for pointing out, I put on the wrong graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve for $z$ in the plane equation:

$$x+z=1 \implies z=1-x$$

Substitute this into the equation for the other surface:

$$\begin{align*}z=1-x\implies x^2+2y^2+(1-x)^2&=1 \\
x^2 - x + y^2 &=0 \\
\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+y^2&=\frac14
\end{align*}$$

which should look familiar.